# Combining two unequal normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, unbiased-estimator

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent, normal distributed random variables with equal mean $\mu$ but non-equal standard deviations $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$.

Suppose I know $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ and I have $n$ samples $x_{11},\ldots,x_{1n}$ from $X_1$ and m samples $x_{21}, \ldots, x_{2m}$ from $X_2$, what is the best estimator for $\mu$? What is its distribution?

(edit: I'm mainly interested in the n=1, m=1 case)

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: This question for the case $n=1$, $m=1$ is answered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12251/determining-true-mean-from-noisy-observations .  The reply shows how to obtain the answer in general.

Comment: @John: I need it at my job - why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is analogous to fixed-effect meta-analysis. The best ([minimum-variance unbiased](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-variance_unbiased_estimator)) estimator would be the [inverse-variance weighted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting) mean 
$$\hat{\mu} = \frac{ \frac{1}{\sigma_1^2} \sum x_{1i} + \frac{1}{\sigma_2^2} \sum x_{2i} }{n/\sigma_1^2 + m/\sigma_2^2}$$

When $n=m=1$ that reduces to
$$\hat{\mu} = \frac{ x_{11} / \sigma_1^2  + x_{21} / \sigma_2^2 }{1/\sigma_1^2 + 1/\sigma_2^2}$$
The distribution of $\hat\mu$ is normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{ 1 }{n/\sigma_1^2 + m/\sigma_2^2}$.