# Combine two estimates of same variable

Tags: estimation, unbiased-estimator, hierarchical-clustering

Suppose I know that $ A = 0.3 \cdot B + 0.7 \cdot C $ 
And I have these estimates:
$$ \hat A = A + \varepsilon $$
$$ \hat B = B + \zeta $$
$$ \hat C = C + \eta $$
For the sake of the argument, $ \varepsilon \space \zeta$ and $\eta$ are non-correlated white noise. I could have some estimate on their variance.

What's a way to get an estimate of $A$?

Comment: It depends on what $\varepsilon,$ $\zeta,$ and $\eta$ mean, how they have been measured or estimated, and what assumptions you make about them.  Please provide those details.

Comment: Thanks whuber, edited that

Comment: We have two independent and unbiased estimators for $A$, namely $0.3\hat B + 0.7\hat C$ and $\hat{A}$. If you knew the variance of your noise parameters, you could use precision weighting to combine the estimates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting

Comment: Got it @JohnMadden. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two obvious independent (unbiased) estimates of $A:$ $\hat A$ and $0.3\hat B + 0.7\hat C.$  Their variances are easily expressed in terms of the variances of the three noise terms.  The minimum-variance unbiased estimate of $A$ obtained from those two estimates is their weighted average with weights inversely proportional to the variances: see [Determining true mean from noisy observations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12251).