Estimating from two sensors
We want to measure the distance between two objects. One sensor gives a reading of 120. Other sensor gives a reading of 200. We know that the readings of the first sensor has a Standard Deviation of 20 and the readings of the second sensor hae a standard deviation of 30.
What is the best estimate?
Part 2 of the Problem
The sensors are in the plane and measure the distance to the dock. If we overestimate the plane would crash. I want the distance with almost 95% confidence that it won't crash.  What is my best estimate of the distance now?

Your first question is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12251.  Your second one is interesting but is not completely formulated: please tell us in terms that can be quantified what you mean by "okay with."  You likely will also need to explain the sense of "best" in this situation as well as providing distributional assumptions about the sensor errors.

@whuber I changed and updated the problem. Does this help to describe what is "best"

It partially helps, but it trivializes the problem: since the sensor readings have some error and assuming you cannot afford to crash the plane, then you won't estimate the distance at all.  You will land in some other fashion or using other information.  Mathematically, the solution is to underestimate as much as possible. Assuming an estimate cannot be negative, you will always estimate the distance is zero.

@whuber What if now I provide that I don't need full surety but atleast some like 90% or 95% or p?

This seems to be related to a homework or self-study exercise. If so, please look at the guidance about "Homework" on this help page. If that's the case, it's best if you could edit the question to say more about what you've tried so far and where you are stuck.
