Why does inverse variance weights in Weighted Least Squares (WLS) Regression give the "best" estimator?
Here is what I have understood about WLS so far.
In OLS, we give each data point equal weightage. This gives the best linear unbiased estimator under certain assumptions -- one of it is constant variance of the error term (homoskedastcicity)
But when the residuals have heteroskedasticity, we determine that the OLS estimator of the regression coefficient is not the "best" one anymore. Which means it has more variance. So, this best estimator is then found using WLS (considering errors are still uncorrelated).
I've read that when the weights are inverse variance of the error term, then WLS gives the best estimator of the regression coefficient. Which means we give less weightage to data points where the OLS model predicts high error variance (estimated by residual variances). More weightage is given to points that have less error variance.
I understand that this works theoretically. I want to understand it more intuitively: why does giving more weightage to less variance points improve the estimator?
Why are less variance points considered more "reliable" for the purpose of performing a WLS regression?
Thank you :)

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12251.


I want to understand it more intuitively: why does giving more weightage to less variance points improve the estimator?

Say you're weighing something that weighs several tons. One scale reports the correct weight plus an error whose expected value is zero and whose standard deviation is one pound. If the errors are normally distributed, then about 68% of the time the reported weight is not more than one pound off. Another scale is the same except that the standard deviation is 100 pounds. So 68% of the time it's off by not more than 100 pounds. So the question is: Why give more weight to the more accurate scale?
Suppose your estimate of the weight is $w$ times the weight reported by the more accurate scale plus $1-w$ times the weight reported by the less accurate scale. Then the variance of the error is
\begin{align}
& w^2\cdot\big(\text{1 pound}\big)^2 + (1-w)^2 \cdot\big(\text{100 pounds} \big)^2. \\[8pt]
= {} & w^2\cdot \big(\big(\text{1 pound}\big)^2 + \big( \text{100 pounds} \big)^2 \big) \\ & {}\qquad {} - 2w\cdot{}\big( \text{100 pounds} \big)^2 + \big(\text{100 pounds} \big)^2 \\[8pt]
= {} & (1^2+100^2) \text{ pound}^2 \left( w^2 - 2w\cdot\frac{100^2}{1^2+100^2} \right) \\[4pt] & {}\qquad\qquad {} + \big( \text{100 pounds} \big)^2 \\[12pt]
= {} & \overbrace{(1^2+100^2) \text{ pound}^2 \left(w^2 - 2w\cdot\frac{100^2}{1^2+100^2} + \left( \frac{100^2}{1^2+100^2} \right)^2 \right)}^\text{completing the square} \\[4pt]
& {} \qquad\qquad {} + \big( \text{100 pounds} \big)^2 - \frac{(100^2)^2}{1^2 + 100^2} \text{ pound}^2 \\[12pt]
= {} & (1^2+100^2) \text{ pound}^2 \left( w - \frac{100^2}{1^2+100^2} \right)^2 \\[4pt]
& {} \qquad\qquad{} + \big( \text{an expression with no “$w$” in it} \big)
\end{align}
The question is how to chose $w$ to make this error variance as small as possible. The answer is that the first term, with $\text{“}w\text{”}$ in it, is $0$ if $w = \dfrac{100^2}{1^2+100^2}$ and is greater than $0$ otherwise. So $w$ should be that former amount:
$$
w = \frac{100^2}{1^2 + 100^2} = 0.9999\,0000\, \underbrace{9999\,0000}_{ \begin{smallmatrix} \text{This part} \\ \text{repeats} \\ \text{forever.} \end{smallmatrix}} \, \ldots
$$

Thank you for the detail. I understand why less variance is more credible when it comes to measurements and you’ve shown that very well.
But I still don’t understand it in WLS— how it helps in getting the best estimator of the regression coefficient. One explanation I’ve read is that if variance is more, it means there could be other cofounders as well and so it should be given less weight. Not sure though.

@DammalapatiSaiKrishna : My answer explicitly explains why in the case of just two random variables, they should have weights proportional to the reciprocals of the variances.
