# $X+Y=s$ but $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Tags: normal-distribution, independence

[From another Cross Validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/585858/247274)

> Given $X\sim N(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2)$ are independent, and you know $X+Y=s$. What is the expected value of $X$?

The question makes it sound like $Y=s-X$ yet $X$ and $Y$ are independent. How can this be?

$$cov(X,Y)\\=cov(X,s-X)\\=-var(X)\ne 0$$

Nonzero covariance is one form of dependence and precludes independence.

Comment: See if the image at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9073/2958 helps

Comment: It isn't that the RVs are deterministically adding to $s$, rather the question is asking about conditioning on the event.

Comment: @Ben That seems to be the approach taken in the other question, not an assumption of the problem faced in the interview.

Comment: I agree with @Ben and have interpreted the questions as asking for the conditional expectation of $X$ given $X+Y=s$ for a specific (realized) $s$.

Comment: Hi @Dave. Writing mathematical expressions in plain English necessarily leads to imprecision. "If $X+Y=s$, what is the expectation of $X$" is just slightly sloppy wording for a conditional expectation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ben's [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/585867/xy-s-but-x-and-y-are-independent/585884#comment1082342_585867)   pretty much says it all.

$X, Y$ being independent doesn't mean there cannot be an event where their added realisations have a particular aggregate, say $s.$ But the distinction must be noted: $$Y :\ne X-s;$$ the necessary condition of independence is uncorrelatedness, i.e. $\mathbb{Cov}(X, Y) = 0,$ but in no way $Y$ is **defined** to be $X- s. $

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a bit like the idea behind collider bias, the reverse of confounding bias.

- Confounding bias: x and y are found to be correlated because both are caused by z.
- Collider bias: x and y are found to be correlated because they both cause
  z and there is a selection effect based on z.

[image: example of bias]

Image from the question:[Can spurious correlations exist in the (theoretical) population?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/579203)

So $X$ and $Y$ may not be correlated, but when you condition on $s$ then they are correlated.

---

It is written a bit implicitly in the interview question but the statement implies a conditioning

> Given that ... and you know $X+Y=s$

You might assume that this means a *particular* sampled individual case has $X+Y=s$. Otherwise there is a contradiction. $X$ and $Y$ can not be independent while also $X+Y=s$.