# X, Y are independent normal distributions, find E[X | X+Y = s]

Tags: normal-distribution

- $X\sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2), Y \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ are independent, find $E[X|X+Y=s]$
- I found the result in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/intuitive-explanation-of-contribution-to-sum-of-two-normally-distributed-random/9073#9073), but I don't know how to derive it
- my approach

$$
E[X|X+Y=s] = \int x\; \Pr(X=x | X+Y=s) \; dx\\
= \int x\; \Pr(X=x) \Pr(Y=s-x) \; dx\\
= \int x\; {1\over \sqrt{2\pi} \sigma_1} e^{-{1\over 2} ({x-\mu_1\over \sigma_1})^2 } {1\over \sqrt{2\pi} \sigma_2} e^{-{1\over 2} ({s-x-\mu_2\over \sigma_2})^2 } \; dx\\
$$

- i don't know how to continue from here. This is a quant interview question that is supposed to be calculated by hand, so I guess there is some trick I am missing?

Comment: As explained in many threads here, independent Normal variables are bivariate Normal and linear combinations of multivariate Normals are also Normal.

Comment: @whuber  I know the conclusion, I am asking about the derivation : )

Comment: I just gave you the derivation.  If you need more details, you can find them in the duplicate.